# "How to iterate using foreach and if statement through collection correctly in laravel?"

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach

Suppose I have data like this :

> $student = (name : student1, payment : 200), (name : student2, payment
> : 300), (name : student3, payment : 100)

and

> $payment = (payment : 200, student : student1), (payment : 300,
> student : student2), (payment : 300, student : student2)

So i have 3 students and several payments linked to student's data and I want to iterate each of them to check their payment history for lets say 2 months duration

What I've done is this :

```
   $tot = 0;
   $counter1 = 0;
   $counter2 = 0;

   foreach($student as $st) {
   $pay = $payment->where('student', $st->name);
       
       foreach($pay as $p) {
           $tot += $p->payment;
           if($tot - (2 * $st->payment) < 0) {
               $counter1 += 1;
           } else {
               $counter2 += 1;
           }
       }
    }
```

The problem is that $tot variable always count all the records from $pay variable (not just count it for each students), resulting the count produced become invalid, for example student3 have not paid at all, but because the $tot counted all the record existed, student3 counted as paid, I hope you guys understand my explanation, feel free to comment if any of my explanation confuse you, and I really hope someone can help me answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description i assume that you need to get sum of amount paid by each students, lets assume student and payment collections as below,

```
$student = collect([
    ['name'=>'s1','payment'=>200],
    ['name'=>'s2','payment'=>300],
    ['name'=>'s3','payment'=>100],
])
$payment = collect([
    ['student'=>'s1','payment'=>200],
    ['student'=>'s2','payment'=>300],
    ['student'=>'s2','payment'=>100],
])
```

So to get the total sum of amount paid by each students

```
$tot = [];
$counter1 = 0;
$counter2 = 0;
foreach($student as $st) {
    $tot[$st['name']] = $payment->where('student', $st['name'])->sum('payment'); // This results sum of total amount paid by each student
    // if($tot[$st['name']] - (2 * $st['payment']) < 0) {
    //    $counter1 += 1;
    // }
}
// $tot Result
[
    "s1" => 200,
    "s2" => 400,
    "s3" => 0,
]
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: to also get rid of the `foreach` I would use the [`mapWithKeys`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys) or the [`reduce`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-reduce)